# JQuery Conflict With Revolution Slider

Tags: jquery, revolution-slider

I bought Wordpress templemate with Revoultion Slider Included.

Everything works until i put my code for animated ScrollToTop Button - and - i include jquery in it to work fine - here is .js:

```
/*! jQuery v3.6.0 | (c) OpenJS Foundation and other contributors | jquery.org/license */
!function(e,t){"use strict";"object"==typeof module&&"object"==typeof module.exports?module.exports=e.document?t(e,!0):function(e){if(!e.document)throw new Error("jQuery requires a window with a document");return t(e)}:t(e)}("undefined"!=typeof window?window:this,function(C,e){"use strict";var t=[],r=Object.getPrototypeOf,s=t.slice,g=t.flat?function(e){return t.flat.call(e)}:function(e){return t.concat.apply([],e)},u=t.push,i=t.indexOf,n={},o=n.toString,v=n.hasOwnProperty,a=v.toString,l=a.call(Object),y={},m=function(e){return"function"==typeof e&&"number"!=typeof e.nodeType&&"function"!=typeof e.item},x=function(e){return null!=e&&e===e.window},E=C.document,c={type:!0,src:!0,nonce:!0,noModule:!0};function b(e,t,n){var r,i,o=(n=n||E).createElement("script");if(o.text=e,t)for(r in c)(i=t[r]||t.getAttribute&&t.getAttribute(r))&&o.setAttribute(r,i);n.head.appendChild(o).parentNode.removeChild(o)}function w(e){return null==e?e+"":"object"==typeof e||"function"==typeof e?n[o.call(e)]||"object":typeof e}var f="3.6.0",S=function(e,t){return new S.fn.init(e,t)};function p(e){var t=!!e&&"length"in e&&e.length,n=w(e);return!m(e)&&!x(e)&&("array"===n||0===t||"number"==typeof t&&0<t&&t-1 in e)}S.fn=S.prototype={jquery:f,constructor:S,length:0,toArray:function(){return s.call(this)},get:function(e){return null==e?s.call(this):e<0?this[e+this.length]:this[e]},pushStack:function(e){var t=S.merge(this.constructor(),e);return t.prevObject=this,t},each:function(e){return S.each(this,e)},map:function(n){return this.pushStack(S.map(this,function(e,t){return n.call(e,t,e)}))},slice:function(){return this.pushStack(s.apply(this,arguments))},first:function(){return this.eq(0)},last:function(){return this.eq(-1)},even:function(){return this.pushStack(S.grep(this,function(e,t){return(t+1)%2}))},odd:function(){return this.pushStack(S.grep(this,function(e,t){return t%2}))},eq:function(e){var t=this.length,n=+e+(e<0?t:0);return this.pushStack(0<=n&&n<t?[this[n]]:[])},end:function(){return this.prevObject||this.constructor()},push:u,sort:t.sort,splice:t.splice},S.extend=S.fn.extend=function(){var e,t,n,r,i,o,a=arguments[0]||{},s=1,u=arguments.length,l=!1;for("boolean"==typeof a&&(l=a,a=arguments[s]||{},s++),"object"==typeof a||m(a)||(a={}),s===u&&(a=this,s--);s<u;s++)if(null!=(e=arguments[s]))for(t in e)r=e[t],"__proto__"!==t&&a!==r&&(l&&r&&(S.isPlainObject(r)||(i=Array.isArray(r)))?(n=a[t],o=i&&!Array.isArray(n)?[]:i||S.isPlainObject(n)?n:{},i=!1,a[t]=S.extend(l,o,r)):void 0!==r&&(a[t]=r));return a},S.extend({expando:"jQuery"+(f+Math.random()).replace(/\D/g,""),isReady:!0,error:function(e){throw new Error(e)},noop:function(){},isPlainObject:function(e){var t,n;return!(!e||"[object Object]"!==o.call(e))&&(!(t=r(e))||"function"==typeof(n=v.call(t,"constructor")&&t.constructor)&&a.call(n)===l)},isEmptyObject:function(e){var t;for(t in e)return!1;return!0},globalEval:function(e,t,n){b(e,{nonce:t&&t.nonce},n)},each:function(e,t){var n,r=0;if(p(e)){for(n=e.length;r<n;r++)if(!1===t.call(e[r],r,e[r]))break}else for(r in e)if(!1===t.call(e[r],r,e[r]))break;return e},makeArray:function(e,t){var n=t||[];return null!=e&&(p(Object(e))?S.merge(n,"string"==typeof e?[e]:e):u.call(n,e)),n},inArray:function(e,t,n){return null==t?-1:i.call(t,e,n)},merge:function(e,t){for(var n=+t.length,r=0,i=e.length;r<n;r++)e[i++]=t[r];return e.length=i,e},grep:function(e,t,n){for(var r=[],i=0,o=e.length,a=!n;i<o;i++)!t(e[i],i)!==a&&r.push(e[i]);return r},map:function(e,t,n){var r,i,o=0,a=[];if(p(e))for(r=e.length;o<r;o++)null!=(i=t(e[o],o,n))&&a.push(i);else for(o in e)null!=(i=t(e[o],o,n))&&a.push(i);return g(a)},guid:1,support:y}),"function"==typeof Symbol&&(S.fn[Symbol.iterator]=t[Symbol.iterator]),S.each("Boolean Number String Function Array Date RegExp Object Error Symbol".split(" "),function(e,t){n["[object "+t+"]"]=t.toLowerCase()});var d=function(n){var e,d,b,o,i,h,f,g,w,u,l,T,C,a,E,v,s,c,y,S="sizzle"+1*new Date,p=n.document,k=0,r=0,m=ue(),x=ue(),A=ue(),N=ue(),j=function(e,t){return e===t&&(l=!0),0},D={}.hasOwnProperty,t=[],q=t.pop,L=t.push,H=t.push,O=t.slice,P=function(e,t){for(var n=0,r=e.length;n<r;n++)if(e[n]===t)return n;return-1},R="checked|selected|async|autofocus|autoplay|controls|defer|disabled|hidden|ismap|loop|multiple|open|readonly|required|scoped",M="[\\x20\\t\\r\\n\\f]",I="(?:\\\\[\\da-fA-F]{1,6}"+M+"?|\\\\[^\\r\\n\\f]|[\\w-]|[^\0-\\x7f])+",W="\\["+M+"*("+I+")(?:"+M+"*([*^$|!~]?=)"+M+"*(?:'((?:\\\\.|[^\\\\'])*)'|\"((?:\\\\.|[^\\\\\"])*)\"|("+I+"))|)"+M+"*\\]",F=":("+I+")(?:\\((('((?:\\\\.|[^\\\\'])*)'|\"((?:\\\\.|[^\\\\\"])*)\")|((?:\\\\.|[^\\\\()[\\]]|"+W+")*)|.*)\\)|)",B=new RegExp(M+"+","g"),$=new RegExp("^"+M+"+|((?:^|[^\\\\])(?:\\\\.)*)"+M+"+$","g"),_=new RegExp("^"+M+"*,"+M+"*"),z=new RegExp("^"+M+"*([>+~]|"+M+")"+M+"*"),U=new RegExp(M+"|>"),X=new RegExp(F),V=new RegExp("^"+I+"$"),G={ID:new RegExp("^#("+I+")"),CLASS:new RegExp("^\\.("+I+")"),TAG:new RegExp("^("+I+"|[*])"),ATTR:new RegExp("^"+W),PSEUDO:new RegExp("^"+F),CHILD:new RegExp("^:(only|first|last|nth|nth-last)-(child|of-type)(?:\\("+M+"*(even|odd|(([+-]|)(\\d*)n|)"+M+"*(?:([+-]|)"+M+"*(\\d+)|))"+M+"*\\)|)","i"),bool:new RegExp("^(?:"+R+")$","i"),needsContext:new RegExp("^"+M+"*[>+~]|:(even|odd|eq|gt|lt|nth|first|last)(?:\\("+M+"*((?:-\\d)?\\d*)"+M+"*\\)|)(?=[^-]|$)","i")},Y=/HTML$/i,Q=/^(?:input|select|textarea|button)$/i,J=/^h\d$/i,K=/^[^{]+\{\s*\[native \w/,Z=/^(?:#([\w-]+)|(\w+)|\.([\w-]+))$/,ee=/[+~]/,te=new RegExp("\\\\[\\da-fA-F]{1,6}"+M+"?|\\\\([^\\r\\n\\f])","g"),ne=function(e,t){var n="0x"+e.slice(1)-65536;return t||(n<0?String.fromCharCode(n+65536):String.fromCharCode(n>>10|55296,1023&n|56320))},re=/([\0-\x1f\x7f]|^-?\d)|^-$|[^\0-\x1f\x7f-\uFFFF\w-]/g,ie=function(e,t){return t?"\0"===e?"\ufffd":e.slice(0,-1)+"\\"+e.charCodeAt(e.length-1).toString(16)+" ":"\\"+e},oe=function(){T()},ae=be(function(e){return!0===e.disabled&&"fieldset"===e.nodeName.toLowerCase()},{dir:"parentNode",next:"legend"});try{H.apply(t=O.call(p.childNodes),p.childNodes),t[p.childNodes.length].nodeType}catch(e){H={apply:t.length?function(e,t){L.apply(e,O.call(t))}:function(e,t){var n=e.length,r=0;while(e[n++]=t[r++]);e.length=n-1}}}function se(t,e,n,r){var i,o,a,s,u,l,c,f=e&&e.ownerDocument,p=e?e.nodeType:9;if(n=n||[],"string"!=typeof t||!t||1!==p&&9!==p&&11!==p)return n;if(!r&&(T(e),e=e||C,E)){if(11!==p&&(u=Z.exec(t)))if(i=u[1]){if(9===p){if(!(a=e.getElementById(i)))return n;if(a.id===i)return n.push(a),n}else if(f&&(a=f.getElementById(i))&&y(e,a)&&a.id===i)return n.push(a),n}else{if(u[2])return H.apply(n,e.getElementsByTagName(t)),n;if((i=u[3])&&d.getElementsByClassName&&e.getElementsByClassName)return H.apply(n,e.getElementsByClassName(i)),n}if(d.qsa&&!N[t+" "]&&(!v||!v.test(t))&&(1!==p||"object"!==e.nodeName.toLowerCase())){if(c=t,f=e,1===p&&(U.test(t)||z.test(t))){(f=ee.test(t)&&ye(e.parentNode)||e)===e&&d.scope||((s=e.getAttribute("id"))?s=s.replace(re,ie):e.setAttribute("id",s=S)),o=(l=h(t)).length;while(o--)l[o]=(s?"#"+s:":scope")+" "+xe(l[o]);c=l.join(",")}try{return H.apply(n,f.querySelectorAll(c)),n}catch(e){N(t,!0)}finally{s===S&&e.removeAttribute("id")}}}return g(t.replace($,"$1"),e,n,r)}function ue(){var r=[];return function e(t,n){return r.push(t+" ")>b.cacheLength&&delete e[r.shift()],e[t+" "]=n}}function le(e){return e[S]=!0,e}function ce(e){var t=C.createElement("fieldset");try{return!!e(t)}catch(e){return!1}finally{t.parentNode&&t.parentNode.removeChild(t),t=null}}function fe(e,t){var n=e.split("|"),r=n.length;while(r--)b.attrHandle[n[r]]=t}function pe(e,t){var n=t&&e,r=n&&1===e.nodeType&&1===t.nodeType&&e.sourceIndex-t.sourceIndex;if(r)return r;if(n)while(n=n.nextSibling)if(n===t)return-1;return e?1:-1}function de(t){return function(e){return"input"===e.nodeName.toLowerCase()&&e.type===t}}function he(n){return function(e){var t=e.nodeName.toLowerCase();return("input"===t||"button"===t)&&e.type===n}}function ge(t){return function(e){return"form"in e?e.parentNode&&!1===e.disabled?"label"in e?"label"in e.parentNode?e.parentNode.disabled===t:e.disabled===t:e.isDisabled===t||e.isDisabled!==!t&&ae(e)===t:e.disabled===t:"label"in e&&e.disabled===t}}function ve(a){return le(function(o){return o=+o,le(function(e,t){var n,r=a([],e.length,o),i=r.length;while(i--)e[n=r[i]]&&(e[n]=!(t[n]=e[n]))})})}function ye(e){return e&&"undefined"!=typeof e.getElementsByTagName&&e}for(e in d=se.support={},i=se.isXML=function(e){var t=e&&e.namespaceURI,n=e&&(e.ownerDocument||e).documentElement;return!Y.test(t||n&&n.nodeName||"HTML")},T=se.setDocument=function(e){var t,n,r=e?e.ownerDocument||e:p;return r!=C&&9===r.nodeType&&r.documentElement&&(a=(C=r).documentElement,E=!i(C),p!=C&&(n=C.defaultView)&&n.top!==n&&(n.addEventListener?n.addEventListener("unload",oe,!1):n.attachEvent&&n.attachEvent("onunload",oe)),d.scope=ce(function(e){return a.appendChild(e).appendChild(C.createElement("div")),"undefined"!=typeof e.querySelectorAll&&!e.querySelectorAll(":scope fieldset div").length}),d.attributes=ce(function(e){return e.className="i",!e.getAttribute("className")}),d.getElementsByTagName=ce(function(e){return e.appendChild(C.createComment("")),!e.getElementsByTagName("*").length}),d.getElementsByClassName=K.test(C.getElementsByClassName),d.getById=ce(function(e){return a.appendChild(e).id=S,!C.getElementsByName||!C.getElementsByName(S).length}),d.getById?(b.filter.ID=function(e){var t=e.replace(te,ne);return function(e){return e.getAttribute("id")===t}},b.find.ID=function(e,t){if("undefined"!=typeof t.getElementById&&E){var n=t.getElementById(e);return n?[n]:[]}}):(b.filter.ID=function(e){var n=e.replace(te,ne);return function(e){var t="undefined"!=typeof e.getAttributeNode&&e.getAttributeNode("id");return t&&t.value===n}},b.find.ID=function(e,t){if("undefined"!=typeof t.getElementById&&E){var n,r,i,o=t.getElementById(e);if(o){if((n=o.getAttributeNode("id"))&&n.value===e)return[o];i=t.getElementsByName(e),r=0;while(o=i[r++])if((n=o.getAttributeNode("id"))&&n.value===e)return[o]}return[]}}),b.find.TAG=d.getElementsByTagName?function(e,t){return"undefined"!=typeof t.getElementsByTagName?t.getElementsByTagName(e):d.qsa?t.querySelectorAll(e):void 0}:function(e,t){var n,r=[],i=0,o=t.getElementsByTagName(e);if("*"===e){while(n=o[i++])1===n.nodeType&&r.push(n);return r}return o},b.find.CLASS=d.getElementsByClassName&&function(e,t){if("undefined"!=typeof t.getElementsByClassName&&E)return t.getElementsByClassName(e)},s=[],v=[],(d.qsa=K.test(C.querySelectorAll))&&(ce(function(e){var t;a.appendChild(e).innerHTML="<a id='"+S+"'></a><select id='"+S+"-\r\\' msallowcapture=''><option selected=''></option></select>",e.querySelectorAll("[msallowcapture^='']").length&&v.push("[*^$]="+M+"*(?:''|\"\")"),e.querySelectorAll("[selected]").length||v.push("\\["+M+"*(?:value|"+R+")"),e.querySelectorAll("[id~="+S+"-]").length||v.push("~="),(t=C.createElement("input")).setAttribute("name",""),e.appendChild(t),e.querySelectorAll("[name='']").length||v.push("\\["+M+"*name"+M+"*="+M+"*(?:''|\"\")"),e.querySelectorAll(":checked").length||v.push(":checked"),e.querySelectorAll("a#"+S+"+*").length||v.push(".#.+[+~]"),e.querySelectorAll("\\\f"),v.push("[\\r\\n\\f]")}),ce(function(e){e.innerHTML="<a href='' disabled='disabled'></a><select disabled='disabled'><option/></select>";var t=C.createElement("input");t.setAttribute("type","hidden"),e.appendChild(t).setAttribute("name","D"),e.querySelectorAll("[name=d]").length&&v.push("name"+M+"*[*^$|!~]?="),2!==e.querySelectorAll(":enabled").length&&v.push(":enabled",":disabled"),a.appendChild(e).disabled=!0,2!==e.querySelectorAll(":disabled").length&&v.push(":enabled",":disabled"),e.querySelectorAll("*,:x"),v.push(",.*:")})),(d.matchesSelector=K.test(c=a.matches||a.webkitMatchesSelector||a.mozMatchesSelector||a.oMatchesSelector||a.msMatchesSelector))&&ce(function(e){d.disconnectedMatch=c.call(e,"*"),c.call(e,"[s!='']:x"),s.push("!=",F)}),v=v.length&&new RegExp(v.join("|")),s=s.length&&new RegExp(s.join("|")),t=K.test(a.compareDocumentPosition),y=t||K.test(a.contains)?function(e,t){var n=9===e.nodeType?e.documentElement:e,r=t&&t.parentNode;return e===r||!(!r||1!==r.nodeType||!(n.contains?n.contains(r):e.compareDocumentPosition&&16&e.compareDocumentPosition(r)))}:function(e,t){if(t)while(t=t.parentNode)if(t===e)return!0;return!1},j=t?function(e,t){if(e===t)return l=!0,0;var n=!e.compareDocumentPosition-!t.compareDocumentPosition;return n||(1&(n=(e.ownerDocument||e)==(t.ownerDocument||t)?e.compareDocumentPosition(t):1)||!d.sortDetached&&t.compareDocumentPosition(e)===n?e==C||e.ownerDocument==p&&y(p,e)?-1:t==C||t.ownerDocument==p&&y(p,t)?1:u?P(u,e)-P(u,t):0:4&n?-1:1)}:function(e,t){if(e===t)return l=!0,0;var n,r=0,i=e.parentNode,o=t.parentNode,a=[e],s=[t];if(!i||!o)return e==C?-1:t==C?1:i?-1:o?1:u?P(u,e)-P(u,t):0;if(i===o)return pe(e,t);n=e;while(n=n.parentNode)a.unshift(n);n=t;while(n=n.parentNode)s.unshift(n);while(a[r]===s[r])r++;return r?pe(a[r],s[r]):a[r]==p?-1:s[r]==p?1:0}),C},se.matches=function(e,t){return se(e,null,null,t)},se.matchesSelector=function(e,t){if(T(e),d.matchesSelector&&E&&!N[t+" "]&&(!s||!s.test(t))&&(!v||!v.test(t)))try{var n=c.call(e,t);if(n||d.disconnectedMatch||e.document&&11!==e.document.nodeType)return n}catch(e){N(t,!0)}return 0<se(t,C,null,[e]).length},se.contains=function(e,t){return(e.ownerDocument||e)!=C&&T(e),y(e,t)},se.attr=function(e,t){(e.ownerDocument||e)!=C&&T(e);var n=b.attrHandle[t.toLowerCase()],r=n&&D.call(b.attrHandle,t.toLowerCase())?n(e,t,!E):void 0;return void 0!==r?r:d.attributes||!E?e.getAttribute(t):(r=e.getAttributeNode(t))&&r.specified?r.value:null},se.escape=function(e){return(e+"").replace(re,ie)},se.error=function(e){throw new Error("Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "+e)},se.uniqueSort=function(e){var t,n=[],r=0,i=0;if(l=!d.detectDuplicates,u=!d.sortStable&&e.slice(0),e.sort(j),l){while(t=e[i++])t===e[i]&&(r=n.push(i));while(r--)e.splice(n[r],1)}return u=null,e},o=se.getText=function(e){var t,n="",r=0,i=e.nodeType;if(i){if(1===i||9===i||11===i){if("string"==typeof e.textContent)return e.textContent;for(e=e.firstChild;e;e=e.nextSibling)n+=o(e)}else if(3===i||4===i)return e.nodeValue}else while(t=e[r++])n+=o(t);return n},(b=se.selectors={cacheLength:50,createPseudo:le,match:G,attrHandle:{},find:{},relative:{">":{dir:"parentNode",first:!0}," ":{dir:"parentNode"},"+":{dir:"previousSibling",first:!0},"~":{dir:"previousSibling"}},preFilter:{ATTR:function(e){return e[1]=e[1].replace(te,ne),e[3]=(e[3]||e[4]||e[5]||"").replace(te,ne),"~="===e[2]&&(e[3]=" "+e[3]+" "),e.slice(0,4)},CHILD:function(e){return e[1]=e[1].toLowerCase(),"nth"===e[1].slice(0,3)?(e[3]||se.error(e[0]),e[4]=+(e[4]?e[5]+(e[6]||1):2*("even"===e[3]||"odd"===e[3])),e[5]=+(e[7]+e[8]||"odd"===e[3])):e[3]&&se.error(e[0]),e},PSEUDO:function(e){var t,n=!e[6]&&e[2];return G.CHILD.test(e[0])?null:(e[3]?e[2]=e[4]||e[5]||"":n&&X.test(n)&&(t=h(n,!0))&&(t=n.indexOf(")",n.length-t)-n.length)&&(e[0]=e[0].slice(0,t),e[2]=n.slice(0,t)),e.slice(0,3))}},filter:{TAG:function(e){var t=e.replace(te,ne).toLowerCase();return"*"===e?function(){return!0}:function(e){return e.nodeName&&e.nodeName.toLowerCase()===t}},CLASS:function(e){var t=m[e+" "];return t||(t=new RegExp("(^|"+M+")"+e+"("+M+"|$)"))&&m(e,function(e){return t.test("string"==typeof e.className&&e.className||"undefined"!=typeof e.getAttribute&&e.getAttribute("class")||"")})},ATTR:function(n,r,i){return function(e){var t=se.attr(e,n);return null==t?"!="===r:!r||(t+="","="===r?t===i:"!="===r?t!==i:"^="===r?i&&0===t.indexOf(i):"*="===r?i&&-1<t.indexOf(i):"$="===r?i&&t.slice(-i.length)===i:"~="===r?-1<(" "+t.replace(B," ")+" ").indexOf(i):"|="===r&&(t===i||t.slice(0,i.length+1)===i+"-"))}},CHILD:function(h,e,t,g,v){var y="nth"!==h.slice(0,3),m="last"!==h.slice(-4),x="of-type"===e;return 1===g&&0===v?function(e){return!!e.parentNode}:function(e,t,n){var r,i,o,a,s,u,l=y!==m?"nextSibling":"previousSibling",c=e.parentNode,f=x&&...

-> (...)



var SCROLLcarTOP = {};

/*************************
      Predefined Variables
*************************/ 
   var $window = $(window),
        $document = $(document);

    //Check if function exists
     $.fn.exists = function () {
        return this.length > 0;
    };



  
/*************************
      Scroll to Top
*************************/
  SCROLLcarTOP.scrolltotop = function () {  
      var $scrolltop = $('.car-top');

      $scrolltop.on('click', function () {
          $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: 0
             }, 800);
          $(this).addClass("car-run");
          setTimeout(function(){ $scrolltop.removeClass('car-run');},1000);
          return false;
      });
      $window.on('scroll', function () {   
          if($window.scrollTop() >= 200) {
              $scrolltop.addClass("show");
              $scrolltop.addClass("car-down");
             } else {
               $scrolltop.removeClass("show");
               setTimeout(function(){ $scrolltop.removeClass('car-down');},300);
            }
       });
  }


/****************************************************
     SCROLLcarTOP Window load and functions
****************************************************/

  //Document ready functions
    $document.ready(function () {
        SCROLLcarTOP.scrolltotop();
    });
```

When i put jquery library code -> Revolution Slider dissapear..

Thanks for yours advices.

Greetings,
Rob